# data.frame and get_elev_points. Error in locations$elevation[idx_s[i]:idx_e[i]] <- unlist(resp$height) : replacement has length zero

Tags: elevation

I am trying to use the function get_elevation_points in a data frame, but keep getting the same error:

```
 > #get the API key : et an API Key from https://mapzen.com/developers. Since elevatr will search the environment for the appropriate key, 

 > #it is suggested that you store this in your .Renviron file. To do this:
    > 
    > require(sf) 
      require(sp)
    > 
    > cat("mapzen_key=mapzen-XXXXXXX\n", file =
    > file.path(normalizePath("~/"), ".Renviron"), 
    >     append = TRUE) mydata <- st_as_sf(x = Coordinates_alt, 
    >                         coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"),
    >                         crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

    > 

> coordinates(Coordinates_alt) <- cbind(Coordinates_alt$Longitude ,
> Coordinates_alt$Latitude) proj4string(Coordinates_alt) =
> CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0") 
> 
> require(elevatr)
> 
> prj_dd <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
> 
> mydata1 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(df, proj4string = CRS(prj_dd), data
> = df)
> 
> head(mydata1)
```

> > df_elev <- get_elev_point(mydata1, prj = prj_dd, src = "mapzen") df_elev <- get_elev_point(df, prj = prj_dd, src = "mapzen") Error in
> >     locations$elevation[idx_s[i]:idx_e[i]] <- unlist(resp$height) :
> >     replacement has length zero In addition: Warning message: src 'mapzen'
> >     is deprecated and will cease to function after 2018-01-31 due to
> >     shutdown of Mapzen; Use 'epqs' instead for US locations. Still
> >     searching for a global elevation service replacement.

Comment: Is this R or what software/langage etc.?

Comment: Perhaps the warning message is informative here: "Warning message: src 'mapzen' is deprecated and will cease to function after 2018-01-31 due to shutdown of Mapzen".